# Consume XML RSS feed using jquery in a predefined template

Tags: jquery, rss, rss-reader

I want use rss feed to show images on other website using jQuery

XML RSS structure is like

```
<rss version="2.0">  
<channel>  
    <title>Gallery</title>  
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>  
    <description>  Latest Photos</description>  

    <item>  
        <title>First Title of Photo</title>                
        <link >https://www.example.com/image/gallery/1.jpg </link>
        <pubDate>Sun, 17 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>  
        <description>Description of the image </description>  
   </item>

    <item>  
        <title>Second Title of Photo</title>                
        <link >https://www.example.com/image/gallery/2.jpg </link>
        <pubDate>Sun, 18 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>  
        <description>Description of the image </description>  
   </item>

    <item>  
        <title>Third Title of Photo</title>                
        <link >https://www.example.com/image/gallery/3.jpg </link>
        <pubDate>Sun, 18 Dec 2017 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>  
        <description>Description of the image </description>  
   </item> 


</channel>  
</rss>
```

My HTML page has following HTML structure

```
<div id="feed">
  <div class="item">
    <img  src="image-path"/>
    <span class="image-title"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i change below code to work with the above structure..

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var url = 'http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml'; //Data in XML format  
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        url: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + url, //For converting default format to JSON format  
        dataType: 'jsonp', //for making cross domain call  
        success: function(data) {  
            alert('Success');  
            $("#feed").append(data.feed);  
            console.log(data.feed.description);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: I can't find `#rss-default` in your html

Comment: Hi, other code is for reference as i copied it from blog, it should be #feed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through `data.items` and add target data into html. As shown in bottom

```
$.each(data.items, function(i, item){
  $("#feed").append('<div class="item"><img src="'+item.thumbnail+'"/><span class="image-title">'+item.thumbnail+'</span></div>');
});
```

So your code should change to:

```
var url = 'http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml';
$.ajax({  
  type: 'GET',  
  url: "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {    
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item){
        $("#feed").append('<div class="item"><img src="'+item.thumbnail+'"/><span class="image-title">'+item.thumbnail+'</span></div>');
    });
  }  
});
```

Check result in [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ouf26q3r/)